# Does Apache Pig FOREACH require GENERATE?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have never seen an example of FOREACH in Pig Latin without GENERATE. Do all FOREACH statements require GENERATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Syntax of [FOREACH](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#FOREACH), GENERATE block is a part of FOREACH, and you have the choice of simple block or nested block. So the answer is yes, all FOREACH require GENERATE.

```
alias  = FOREACH { gen_blk | nested_gen_blk } [AS schema];
```